Relationship with peers while working remotely from home
Background:
We all work remotely, across the globe, in different timezones, languages, mindsets, etc. Everyone has tight deadlines so we can't text/meet/zoom-meet without any reason. Also, we are afraid of each other because we don't know each other's perceptions. Due to this, some people in the team become the Boss's favorite and then you have to become an ally of that person who is the boss's favorite and then this chain keeps going like an MLM business scheme. This introduces a lot of buttering and bootlicking.
I am a hard worker, and I have a proven record of great work, I have recorded proof of these feats. I am polite, but I talk only when necessary, when I genuinely have doubts, or when I think I can give my contributions.
Still, I got laid off due to unknown reasons, sometimes when I follow up continuously to find out the reason for the layoff they simply say you are good but we are cutting costs, and that's why you have to go away. When the decision is made they don't give me much chance to defend myself, they simply turn off my email (Outlook, or GMail) which is linked to all sorts of communication.
Question is:
How can I avoid this? How can I be Boss's favorite?
I am a contractor I work on an hourly basis.

If you are a contractor, you are not 'laid off'. Your contract is cancelled.
It's more easy to cut down on contractors than employees.

I know that's true. But my question was about favoritism in the workplace. If boot-licking is a skill/talent why there are no classes for that? How can I be my Boss's/Peers' favorite without boot-licking?

Maybe it has nothing to do with boot-licking. Maybe they really are 'cutting costs' and as a contractor your contract is just cancelled. It's more expensive and time consuming hiring a new employee and laying off an employee than to just to have a contractor you can hire and get rid off by the drop of a hat.

Yes, but my question is not about why I got laid off. My question is about how to make healthy relationships with my peers, no matter I am an employee or contractor. It is easy when you meet each other, working from an office, even in Hybrid mode, but when it is completely remote and diversified people. It is a challenge. Other guys from different vendors can establish such relationships. What are they doing extra other than their job, sitting remotely?

Could be "last in first out", could be an alphabetical list with every 3rd one picked. Who can know.

You say the question is not about why you got laid off...but most of your question talks about being laid off and you say things like "How can I avoid this?". That's why you are getting lots of comments about that part.

The way you make healthy relationships with your peers when you work remotely is just like making healthy relationships with your peers when working locally, except more so. That is, you make a deliberate effort to get to know people, to be helpful, to be pleasant to work with, to be productive, to be proactive, and so on.
It does take more conscious effort when you are not seeing people casually every day face to face, having lunch with them, and the like; that is one of the downsides of working remotely.
Ditto for a healthy relationship with your manager. Communicate. Keep them informed of your progress; let them know if you are blocked by something, make sure you know what their priorities are and that you are addressing them, be productive, responsible, and pleasant to work with. Again, this requires a more conscious effort than if you were running into them in the hallway on a regular basis; that comes with working remotely.
Note that you have to be careful not to overcompensate here. You don't want to bury them under so much communication that you become annoying.
If you aren't willing to make that additional effort, remote work may not be good for your career. Even if you are able and willing, there will certainly be opportunities you miss because you aren't in the inner/casual communication loop. As with everything else, it's all trade-offs.

Add value or kiss butt
Smart managers would perfer to have people that add value to a project. Not-so-smart managers like the "buttering and bootlicking".
From your OP, it seems that you're much more comfortable with the "Add Value" option.
Why isn't getting you what you want? Ensure that everything that you do is "Less trouble that it is worth". Not communicating is sometimes perceived negatively. This is important to understand and likely is part of why you are being dropped from projects.
If you have nothing to add, then compliment others that have said something useful. Speak up more with ideas. Someone that hardly communicates can be perceived as not engaged, not interested, incapable, or having an attitude problem. Even if none of things are true - it isn't fair, but it happens.
Being someone that a manager wants to have on the team is more than "just showing up". They need to know that you will proactively help address their interests in the projects when possible.
I am not suggesting to go rouge and be wild. Just be a bit more outgoing on calls and suggesting ideas that will help the projects move forward. Be polite and friendly. When it is feasible, offer to accomplish more.
These will help move you to be the "go to person" for managers. Someone they can trust to get work done quickly, at expected cost, and provide useful feedback.

They prefer asynchronous communication. Be short and send them the message, what do you want. Shortly.
If they don't answer, you can already use it against them. You might try to escalate things. For example:

"Dear Rajan, I need an account to X, in order to deploy our db backend (details are in DBDEVOPS-456 in the jira)"

Then Rajan chooses to ignore you. Fine, two hour later you message to also Rajan and to also Rajans boss or teammate, with the same content.
If you talk with the Boss, then you mention the problem that it is hard to talk with Rajan. You are also messaging the boss/lead for whom you are doing the db deploy, not accusing Rajan, but hinting that he is actively obstacling you. The correct style: "db deployment script is done, and works by me locally. I messaged Rajan about the account, waiting the answer". If it happened 2 days ago and no step forward, boss will understood who is the bottleneck.
If it is hard to talk with everyone, then pick the guy with whom you had the most trouble. Don't accuse him directly, only mention, that it was a problem that it has taken a week for him to create a db account. But, fortunately, meanwhile you could solve the long-standing problem of the test coverage. Roughly that is the right way to shot the largest asshole to the neck from the back. Target always only the worst guy and tolerate the others, reason is very simple: if the boss see that you are the source of all troubles, then he won't see how well are you working.
Most importantly, your bosses are tracking you on multiple ways, but that is never the source code. So, be careful:

document everything what you do (never accusing anyone for ignoring you).
be open, show and document everything what you understood.

Another important thing, I can not say enough times.
You must direct, 1:1 video chat with all of them.
Large part of the long-term remote IT workers become a retard. Somehow nearly-IRL face-to-face talks helps them to temporarily get back into the right track. I am not a psychyatrist to understand its reason, but I experience this since a decade.
Actually, not the reason is important, why you talk with them. If there is no apparent reason, then create one. For example, video call Rajan, roughly with this thing: "Please do a short video session about the db connectivity setup. I think so it would be much more clear and easy."
So, here you offer him, that he will only need to see your face for some minutes, then he won't need to work again. While in the reality, you goal is to help him to become sane again, at least until he fixes your db link.

OP's question is how to make better relationships with coworkers/management, and your answer is to deliberately backstab peers and poison other relationships throughout the office while documenting everything under the assumption that you will need it for proof? What a surefire way to become a paranoid outcast that no one trusts.

@InBedded16 Not as proof, but as information sharing source in an environment where everyone ignores the others. And yeah, being bullied and consistently ignored, exactly that OP has to do: fight until the last shot, and work better as the others together.

@InBedded16 He is an outcast, already now he is an outcast. "Paranoid", that is only your label, in their environment surely no one is using such words. They don't really use words at all. But I see, you don't really like this post. Also you have teammates with whom you rather don't talk and don't do with them anything, but you forget to say it to them, uhm?

@InBedded16 ...and yet another important experience, not directly related to the post, but very well related to you: my decade long experience, exactly those are using the word "paranoid" in a workplace setting, with them a little bit of healthy paranoia is very well reasoned...
